VAR External Intrument in Python
I am trying to replicate the Gertler-Karadi 2015 External Instrument VAR model in python. I am having the issues with the functions. It is not taking values and throwing errors.
I was trying debugging but still it did not work. I was thinking maybe the data needs scaling or normalizing but I may be mistaken.
# Define variables (based on your data)
num_impulses = 40  # number of periods
# based on the given matrices
col_names = ['IP', 'HICP', 'de1y', 'eurostoxx50', 'bbb_spread']  # example column names

# Initialize the impulse response storage
irs = np.zeros([num_lags + num_impulses, num_vars])
# Set initial impulse response (based on the third column of A0)
irs[num_lags, :] = A0[:, 2]  # Correctly initializing with the third column of A0

# Iterate to calculate the impulse responses
for jj in range(1, num_impulses):
    # Extract lagged values for the current impulse response calculation
    lvars = irs[np.arange(start=num_lags + jj - 1, stop=jj - 1, step=-1), :].T
    # Compute the next row of the impulse response
    irs[num_lags + jj, :] = lvars.flatten().T@ Bhat  # Ensure correct dimensions and transpose Bhat

# Slice the relevant impulse response values
irs = irs[num_lags:num_lags + num_impulses, :]

# Convert to DataFrame
irf_chol = pd.DataFrame(irs, columns=col_names)
print(irf_chol.head())

The result is exploding
  IP      HICP        de1y  eurostoxx50  bbb_spread
0   0.000000  0.000000    1.000000     0.412065   -0.355296
1  -0.025553 -0.009461   -0.560410    -1.062703    6.280475
2   0.692767 -0.093960  -20.098512     4.914833   16.835246
3   0.342356  0.788316   91.130221    56.952628 -616.248000
4 -47.819026  0.379773  755.920970  -438.207420  647.235308


too much code, please reduce to this:
minimal reproducible example

please specify which function there are errors with.

So i have added the codes, so after the bootstrap i need to do estimate of the varsb estimate(varsb), this is where things break down
